# How to run a .php file over and over...cron perhaps?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php file that calls exec() on a c++ exe.When the .exe is finishing running I need to run the php file again,repeat .

I am wondering what is the best way to do this? This .php file has no user interaction and needs to be completely automated.

EDIT:Found another solution that would kill the process if it is already running which will cover this issue well.See posts on this page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: if you are using a framework, it can have this kind of function too

Comment: @JMax I will be using codeigniter.Do you have an example?

Comment: In future please ensure you include all relevant information such as framework and update your tags to reflect this

Comment: couldn't you just run the c++ exe with cron? (or is the PHP doing something else at the same time?)

Comment: Hi Spudley.I need to email the user once the .exe completes.I have the users email stored in a Mysql datbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used codeigniter before but there seems to be a solution as described in the [wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category%3aAdvanced%3a%3aCronScript/).

Depending on how you can access the system (if you are admin or not) and depending on how you are planning to update the automated commands, IMHO, you could use both solution (Linux crontab or codeigniter cron script).

Comment: CodeIgniter CronScripts still require editing of the crontab. You should have a user crontab even if you're not an admin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple Linux line that starts up the script in the background and uses the `watch` command to restart the script whenever it finishes running:

```
watch -n 0 php /path/to/script.php &
```

Once you've started it like this, you can use the `ps` command to list running processes and find the process ID for `watch`, and then use `kill process_id` to stop watch.

It's probably not best practice to run commands like this, but it's a quick and easy solution that doesn't require any special access privileges on the system (whereas using cron might), and doesn't involve editing your code (whereas a codeigniter solution will).

Comment: Oh cool.This is exactly what i need.Only where do I put that code?